# Magento - echo added/selected products to wishlist/cart in e-mail

Tags: magento, contact-form, product

I'll try to explain as clear as I can.

When customer adds products to cart and goes to list of chosen products, then click on button "get enquiry", it takes him to contact form page. All been done so far, but what I want to do is when customer sends e-mail, I want receive informations(name of products) of added/chosen products.

in file items.phtml I have this code for items

`<?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
    <?php $countItems = count($_items); ?>
    <?php if($countItems): ?>
        <div>
            <ul id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
                <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>`

I don't know how to pass those infos in e-mail as I'm new to magento.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be included in the share wishlist functionality you can override the wishlist sharing controller action like so:

```
    < frontend >
        < routers >
            < wishlist >
                < args >
                    < modules >
                        < MyCompany_Coreextensions before="Mage_Wishlist" >
                            MyCompany_Coreextensions_Wishlist
                        < /MyCompany_Coreextensions >
                    < /modules >
                < /args >
            < /wishlist >
        < /routers >
    < /frontend >
```

Now in your custom modules folder, create controllers/Wishlist/IndexController.php, and override the sendAction:

```
class MyCompany_Coreextensions_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController
{
    public function sendAction()
    {
       // Copy and paste existing code from sendAction  in app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/indexController.php
    }
}
```

Find the **$emails** variable and append your admin email like so:

```
$emails[] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
```

and it should include you into the email. IF you don't know how to create your own module then [look here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643)

**NOTE:** This is untested code, let me know if you have problems